# The difference between simply installing software & adding to repository

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have a simple question coming from my mind.

What is the difference between :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

And simply

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

Which one should i use & why?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps to what you're running:

1. `add-apt-repository` adds a PPA to your list of sources, so that Ubuntu knows to look for updates from that PPA as well as from the official Ubuntu sources. Usually this is used to allow developers to provide updates more quickly than those in the official Ubuntu repositories.
2. `apt-get update` tells `apt-get` to update its database of what packages can be installed and where to install them from. In this case, `apt-get` will see your newly-added PPA and discover that ppa:maco.m/ruby has the newest version of `rubygems` that it knows about, so it will make a note to install `rubygems` from the PPA next time someone asks to install it.
3. apt-get install causes `apt-get` to find the package in its database and download and install the indicated file. In this case, it will find the `rubygems` package, download it from `ppa:maco.m/ruby`, and install it.

If you were to simply run `apt-get install rubygems`, you would get a less-recent version (or perhaps nothing at all, depending on whether `rubygems` is also in the Ubuntu repositories or only in the PPA).

In general, the format `ppa:a/b` will expand to `https://launchpad.net/~a/+archive/b`, where you can view the files and download them individually. In your case, that would be https://launchpad.net/~maco.m/+archive/ruby.

Comment: Before answering a question, please search for similar questions in this site, and  in the comment section refer to the link that has got the answer or if you can mark as duplicate so that others having the same problem can easily go to the original question :).

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding PPA from

> ppa:cwchien/gradle

, maybe you get the latest work of that packages, but don't mean it without risks (maybe more unstable, etc).

If you're use direct command

> sudo apt-get install gradle

, so you use ubuntu repositories. It usually provide safer and more stable, but it can be outdated version.

So you can choose between them that fits to your needs.